# ¿Buscador con filtro de 2 campos ajax codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo un buscador que filtra por una variable pero no encuentro la forma de realizar la búsqueda pero que lo haga con 2 variables al mismo tiempo.

Este es mi método que uso para filtrar por un solo campo "nombre_evento" de la base de datos "evento" , necesito filtrar al mismo tiempo por otro campo "tipo de evento".[image: imagen del filtro]

```
function mostrar($valor){
    $this->db->like("nombre_evento",$valor);
    $consulta = $this->db->get("evento");
    return $consulta->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En codeigniter puedes usar like el numero de veces que quieras, para buscar por distintas variables por ejemplo podrías hacer algo así:

```
$this->db->like('nombre_evento', $var1);
$this->db->like('tipo_evento', $var2);
```

Si por ejemplo `$var1= "prueba"` y `$var2 = "prueba1"`

Obtendrías una consulta como la siguiente:

```
//WHERE `title` LIKE '%prueba%' ESCAPE '!' AND  `body` LIKE '%prueba1% ESCAPE '!'
```

También es posible utilizar arrays asociativos en la consulta, como:

```
$comparaciones = array('nombre_evento'=>$valor_nombre,'tipo_evento'=>$tipo);
$this->db->like($comparaciones);
```

Extendiendo esto, podrías simplificarlo hasta el punto de utilizar como keys en el ajax los nombres de las columnas de la base de datos. De esta manera se podría pasar el post como variable de comparación.

```
function mostrar(){
    return $this->db->like($this->input->post())->get("evento");
}
```

Recuerda permitir únicamente las peticiones ajax con

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar más parámetros a tu consulta existen 2 maneras (son las que recuerdo)
La primera es así:

```
$this->db->like('campotabla', $paramBuscar); 
$this->db->like('campotabla', $panamBuscar);
```

La otra es crear la consulta aparte y concatenas los parámetros a buscar.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, campo, campo FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($cadena)."%'";
```

Saludos!!

Comment: Giovany, esto no es una respuesta para la pregunta planteada. No te preocupes, estoy seguro que pronto tendras suficiente reputación para comentar. Mientras tanto, te invito a [edit] tu respuesta para que si sea una respuesta para la pregunta o a eliminarla para mantener la calidad del sitio. Saludos!

Comment: Soy nuevo, gracias por el consejo. !!Respuesta actualizada!! :D Saludos!